# Cffi and char** as an argument

Tags: python, c, python-cffi, cffi

I have a following code in Python, using cffi:

```
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("int somefunc(char** data);")

lib = ffi.dlopen("somelib")
```

Now, I want to call the `somefunc` with `char**` and get the data to Python. `somefunc` actually fills the `data`, so:

```
data = ffi.new("char**", ffi.NULL)
lib.somefunc(data)
```

So how am I now supposed to get the result from the `data` variable to a Python string? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: In C, `char**` and `char[][]` are basically the same thing.

Comment: See also https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#an-example-of-calling-a-main-like-thing

Comment: Also, make it `char **data`, not `char** data` -- the former is much less surprising in terms of how it behaves when you define multiple variables on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

`data[0]` or `data[n]` gives you the n-th item in the array.  (If there is only one string, that will be `data[0]`; I think it is the case based on details in your question.)  That's still a `char *`, but you can interpret like a null-terminated byte string using `ffi.string(data[0])`.  As usual, you might then have to decode that byte string to a normal unicode string using the right encoding.

The full program looks like:

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("int somefunc(char** data);")

lib = ffi.dlopen("somelib")
data = ffi.new("char**", ffi.NULL)
lib.somefunc(data)

value = ffi.string(data[0])
```